# Javascript remove ckeditor plugins on load

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

**Html:**

```
<textarea name="Editor" class="ckeditor" id="aboutme">@Model.Content</textarea>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
    config.removePlugins = 'elementspath,save,font';
</script>
```

When page load , i want to disable all ckeditor plugins.I tried above code however it did not work for me.

How can i remove plugins by javascript on load of page ?

Any help appreciates.
Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can define a list of plugins to load ([`CKEDITOR.config#plugins`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-plugins)):

```
config.plugins = 'wysiwygarea,toolbar,basicstyles,...';
```

But you can also restrict existing (default) list of plugins ([`CKEDITOR.config#removePlugins`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-removePlugins)):

```
config.removePlugins = 'link,...';
```

Both options can be defined globally (`config.js`) or for a particular editor instance like

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    removePlugins: 'link'
} );
```

Please refer to official [*Setting Configuration*](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration) guide to know more.

**Note**: Since CKEditor 4.1, the presence of a plugin determines whether certain type content associated with that plugin is allowed or disallowed. Read more about [*Advanced Content Filter*](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter).

Comment: Where does the `'editor1'` name come from?  When do you run that code, is that only when first initializing the editor?  How can you add/remove plugins once the editor is already loaded?  How does this interact with the `ckeditor()` function itself?  The documentation doesn't explain things very well...

Comment: 'editor1' is the default id for the textarea that you want to replace with ckeditor.  you can change it to whatever the id is in your own html

Comment: @Acyra I want to remove it for all instances of ckeditor which will be created (e.g. DIVs with contenteditable="true" which will become ckeditors in the future when they are clicked on).  How do I do that?  There is no global variable named "config" to set "removePlugs" in. By the time CKEDITOR is defined, it seems to be too late, the plugin is already loaded!

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question in the comment to oleq's answer:

I have a CKEditor instance that I'm using (with jQuery) like so:

```
window.onload = function () {
        $ckTarget = $(".pageContentTextBox");
        if ($(".pageContentTextBox").length > 0) {
            $ckEditor = $ckTarget.ckeditor({
                htmlEncodeOutput: true,
                removePlugins: "link"
            });
        }
};
```

I was able to successfully remove the "link" plugin that way.  I am going to set up an ASP.net User Control with public properties "extraPlugins" and "removePlugins" and insert the values using the client-side yellow tags ("code nuggets") to be able to use this on multiple pages with different plugins enabled/disabled.

I hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit the config.js. This js is loaded/included from the ckeditor.js. config.js is a default custom editor js file. You can remove buttons or your plugins from the editor by including the list of names of elements to remove. For the list of names to remove from the editor please refer to the below link: https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/CKEditor-3.x/config.js-changes-not-reflected

Include the list of buttons or plugins to remove from the editor by appending them to the config.removebuttons and include this line of code in config.js

```
// Remove some buttons provided by the standard plugins, which are
// not needed in the Standard(s) toolbar.
config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript,Image,Flash,Table,HorizontalRule,Smiley...';
```